# Wrapping text around an absolute positioned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm stuck on something where I have a loads of content pages with a message box. In this message box, you could have images, text, headers etc. However each message box will have an Icon in the top right of the box. The image will sit in the top of the box fine if i use position:absolute. However If the message box has a header or a paragraph and fills with the width of the box. The text will sit underneath the image.

I basically need a wrapper around the image which has a width so the text will only go sit up until the edge of the image. I'm 99% sure i got it working in firebug by wrapping the absolute positioned image in a div and giving it some styles. But I can't seem to get it working today!

There are hundreds of pages, so moving the HTML around is not an option. The image doesn't currently have a wrapper. So i'm having to use Jquery to wrap the image. (That's if it's the answer).

I know that position absolute takes the element outside of the document flow, but is there something I can do?

Anyway here is my code so far:

```
<div class="message">
<h3>Some text, a header perhaps? But this is the next that will sit under the image, sometimes it's a p tag.</h3>
<img class="messageIcon" src="/link-to-icon/which-are-the-same-size" border="0" width="64" >
<p>Some more random text that would appear in the messagebox this could go on for a few lines.</p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.messageIcon').wrap('<div class="messageIconWrap" />');

    alert("this is a test");

});



</script>
```

The JS wraps a div around the image

CSS:

```
.messageIconWrap{
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
}

div.message {
    position: relative;
}
.message {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #393939;
    clear: both;
}

.messageIcon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    float: right;
}
```

JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jdp7E/

Comment: Any place where we can see this? or can you set it up on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Can't you just but the image into the HTML code for your message box first, and then just `float`it to the right?

Comment: No, like i said there no hundreds of pages where it's already been added. Updated ticket with JSfiddle

Comment: What you want is impossible. An absolutely positioned element is no longer part of the flow layout **in any way**, and as such other content cannot interact with it, or flow around it. You need to insert it as inline floating content to achieve the intended effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pure CSS solution: Add a pseudo-element at the beginning of the container with

```
div.message:before { content:" "; float:right; width:75px; height:75px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdp7E/1/

Won't work in older browsers that don't support generated content, so mainly older IE. For those a padding-right for the container could be used as fallback.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it could work. I'll need to check with the client dropping in IE is fine. Could you explain in a little more detail how this actually works?

Comment: Well it just generates a pseudo child element at the beginning of the container, and since it gets floated to the right the text content of the following elements flows around it. Basically what I suggested to you before, just putting the image itself first and float it - but since you said that was not practical in your case, this is a workaround that achieves the same effect without manipulating or adding any markup, and leaves the space under the absolutely positioned image "reserved".

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate it, will give a try. Seems to be what I need in this case. What does the content:" "; do exactly?

Comment: `content` says what the actual content of the generated pseudo element should be – could be any character or an image. Since we don’t need or want anything visible here, I’ve used just a space character. (There _has_ to be “something” as value for the content property, otherwise nothing would be rendered at all).

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps is a very quickie-patchy solution, but how about set a `padding-right` to ".message" as this?

```
div.message {
    position: relative;
    padding-right:80px; /* - You can set a padding higher or equal than the image - */
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzWNV/)**

Comment: I can't as the text needs to wrap around and have the same spacing on the left hand side of the page as right right.

Comment: this is a good and quick solution how ever I prefer to remove position absolute from the icon in these cases

Comment: @JoshDavies My bad :( excuse me! More difficult in this case, let me try, because I'm pretty sure I have your same need about few months ago...

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/mTDwf/)***

What I would suggest doing is calculating the width of the text message, calculating the width of the icon, setting the width of the text message to the percent remaining if the icon's width were removed from the text message width.

```
var mw = $('.message:first-child').width();
var iw = $('.messageIcon').width() + 20;//20 is for padding
var percent = parseInt((mw - iw) / mw * 100);
$('.message :first-child').width(percent+"%");
```